# ASp.NET MVC 2 - find a view embeded in the compiled assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an MVC Application the views was embedded in the compiled dll, how can i get a list of all the views?

I am using reflection to get all the controller info, however, i do not know the view info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you embed a view file into a project (mark the `.aspx` file as embedded resource) it is included into the resulting assembly. To obtain a list of all embedded resources you could use the [GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) method to obtain the file as is but I don't really see the usefulness of this technique.

If on the other hand you want to have views embedded into an assembly and instruct the runtime to use those views instead of the file system you might [need to implement](http://wynia.org/wordpress/2008/12/aspnet-mvc-plugins) a custom [VirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx).

Comment: yup... i got the virtual path provider going... everything works fine, i can call actions on the conpiled assebly by simply throwing the assembly into my bin folder, but i would have liked to be able to scan the assembly for all views and partial views, and maybe get more info on those views

Comment: Then you could use the `GetManifestResourceNames` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx) to enumerate all embedded resources into a given assembly.